# PHP require_once is not working

Tags: php, model-view-controller, mamp, require-once, construct

I am trying to make an interactive php website using MVC framework and on a MAMP server, I am at the first steps of this. 
I am using the following code to access a different page which has a __construct() function to echo some text... but the index.php returns a blank page...

init.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/App.php';
?>
```

the other page code is:

App.php:

```
<?php
class App {
public function __construct() {
   echo 'some text';
     }
}
```

my index.php is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once '../app/init.php';
$app = new App;
?>
```

and I looked at the different solutions and have tried many but still not working. like adding **ROOT** or **DIR** and even **FILE**, knowing that my version of PHP is 7.

help is appreciated... thank you...

Comment: Blank page, try http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Take a look in your apache logs. Where that is will depend on your setup. For me (on a mac) it's /var/log/apache2/error_log. On my linux servers it's /var/log/httpd/error_log

Comment: [`is_readable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) or [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) or else

Comment: @NathanEdwards I have checked the logs folder in Mamp, turned out to have some errors, the errors are as follow:  [Sat May 07 17:20:46 2016] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache] , [Sat May 07 17:30:17 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/MAMP/htdocs/favicon.ico , [07-May-2016 13:26:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'core/Controller.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\MAMP\htdocs\project3da\mvc\app\init.php on line 4

Comment: Looks to me like the init.php you're including is not the one you have above.

Comment: @NathanEdwards i actually had two **require_once** in init.php, one is: `require_once 'core/App.php';` and the second one is : `require_once 'core/Controller.php';` when i commented the line of the second one the value of echo in the App.php file was displayed correctly.

Comment: So either core/Controller.php doesn't exist or your apache server doesn't have the right permissions. I'm guessing the items in core are supposed to be part of your framework?